# How to shut off localization in git 1.8

Tags: git, localization, terminal

I just updated my git to version 1.8 on OSX 10.8.2 following [this tutorial](http://ayanim97.com/mac/installing-and-upgrading-git-mac-os-lion) and now git responds partially in my localization.
e.g.

```
$ git status
# Auf Zweig master  
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

How can I shut this off?

Comment: But how to make this permanent?

Comment: Wow! How bad these localisations are! (just wanted to get that out of my chest, thanks for listening).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `alias` to specifically disable localization:

```
alias git="LANG=en_US git"
```

Put that in your `.profile`/`.bashrc` (or other shell startup script) to make it permanent.

Comment: I added it to ~/.bashrc and ~/.profile but it is still localized. Is that the right path for .bashrc and .profile?

Comment: You may need to restart your shell. Make sure it is the right place to put startup commands (depending on your environment, it may be any one of `.profile`, `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile`, `.login_profile`, or maybe something else if you are not using Bash).

Comment: Problem solved. I added it to the ~/.bash_profile as well now it works.

Comment: I removed it from `.profile` and `.bashrc` and it still works. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You could put the following in your `~/.profile` (or `~/.bashrc`),

```
export LANG=en_US
```

This will apply to all commands that use your locale, not just `git`

Comment: Thanks, but to have it only for git seems better to me.